# In jQuery, how to define a function with a selector as a parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to define a function that would to that:

```
var photoWidth = $('#photo_preview').width();
var photoHeight = $('#photo_preview').height();

if (imgHeight > imgWidth){
    $('#photo_preview').css('width','100');
    }
```

My goal is to create a function that would be like:

```
resizePhoto(theselector);
```

... with the parameter "theselector" being $('#photo_preview') or any other selector.

NOTE: I can't use classes for this one.

What should I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
function resizePhoto(selector){
  var photoWidth = $(selector).width();
  var photoHeight = $(selector).height();

  if (imgHeight > imgWidth){
    $(selector).css('width','100');
  }
}
```

...

```
resizePhoto('#photo_preview'); //Usage
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function(selector) {
    var $jq = $(selector);
    var imgWidth = $jq.width();
    var imgHeight = $jq.height();

    if (imgHeight > imgWidth){
        $jq.css('width','100px');
    }
}
```